# how do i make a api in godot

Tags: godot

I'm trying to make an A.P.I for my dating sim; but i have no idea how do take my already existing code for writing text and re-engineer it to be a part of a A.P.I.

here's my code

```
#DialogueBoxs.gd
extends RichTextLabel

var dialog = [""]
var page = 0

var isDone = false

func _ready():

    set_bbcode(dialog[page])
    set_visible_characters(0)

    set_process_input(true)


func _dialogue(event):
    if event is InputEventMouseButton and event.is_pressed():

        if isDone:
            if page < dialog.size()-1:
                page += 1
                bbcode_text = dialog[page]
                visible_characters = 0
                isDone = false

        else:
            visible_characters = get_total_character_count()
            isDone = true

func _on_Timer_timeout():

    if visible_characters < get_total_character_count():
        visible_characters += 1
        if visible_characters == get_total_character_count():
            isDone = true
```

can someone tell me how do i make this code a part of an A.P.I

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you want to achieve. Please tell us more about the game mechanics.

Comment: My game is a dating sim, you play through an individual girls route and Romance them and at the end of the route you get the girl. I want an api so that I can make a skeleton that holds my Sprites, dialogue, sound, choices and order them the way I want them to be.

Comment: I don't know how to explain this properly I'll give you a demonstration.

Comment: Start chp G.Sprite -> B.sprite -> Bg.music -> Bg.sprite -> G.dialogue -> G.dialogue -> B.dialogue -> B.dialogue end chp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use an API you make calls to a script in order to retrieve information. This script doesn't really look like its getting information, rather its a collection of helper methods and events. In order to create an API you typically link to a database that stores information you would want to send to the user.

Comment: How do I do it in gdscripts

Comment: How about using a JSON file that links all you information at a given state to you script?

Comment: how do i link it in my script. can do this with images(sprites and backgrounds) and sounds as well.

Comment: Basically you load the file with `f = File.new()` and `f.open(path)`. I would use a setter function to monitor the player state and when it changes you parse the JSON file with the built-in parser (or write one on your own). And in you script you simply change everything you want by using something like `background = parse_result[bg]` and `char = parse_result[ch]` in your setter function. Then you continue with your game loop.